# php update dynamic sql rows through form

Tags: php, mysqli

My goal is to retrieve a dynamic SQL list of rows and edit every item in the list within the same page using POST (no multiple changes at once required). Can this be achieved within the same page? I made the script below which displays everything the way i want to, however the switch statement doesn't seem to be fit for purpouse.

I am aware this code might not be best practice (not to mention secure). Sorry for being inflexible, but i'm not allowed to use anything other then PHP/HTML

Code:

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr> <td class="tg">' .$row["id"]. '</td>' . "\n";
    echo '<td class="tg"> <form action= "" method="post"> <input type="text" name="voornaam"      value="'.$row["voornaam"].'" style="width:100px"> <input name="submit" type ="submit"  value="Aanpassen"><br/><br/>' . '</td>' . "\n";
    echo '<td class="tg"> <form action= "" method="post"> <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="'.$row["achternaam"].'" style="width:100px"> <input name="submit" type ="submit"  value="Aanpassen"><br/><br/>' . '</td>' . "\n"; 
    echo '<td class="tg"> <form action= "" method="post"> <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="'.$row["omschrijving"].'" style="width:500px"> <input name="submit" type ="submit"  value="Aanpassen"><br/><br/>' . '</td> </tr>' . "\n";
}
} else {
echo "0 resultaten";
}
switch(!empty($_POST))
{
case !empty($_POST[$row["voornaam"]]):
     // update SQL query 'firstname' here
    break;

}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Since when can you not implement basic security or best practices in PHP?

Comment: I strongly believe that your `switch` statement should be an `if` statement.

Comment: You should make your `UPDATE` query before echoing the datas.

Comment: @emmanuel: to ease it down i gave 1 switch example. Actually there are 4 cases, thats why i figured switch would be easier to read.

Comment: @Machavity: I'm just saying my goal isn't code optimization/securing, so why bother lecturing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this way you actualy see what you are editing and it's more clean.

```
// PDO DB conecction (secure way)
    try {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db_name}", $username, $password);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle connection error
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

if isset($_POST["voornaam"]){
 $stmt = $con->prepare(" QUERY");
        $stmt->execute();
echo "YEAH you did it";
} else {
stmt = $con->prepare(" QUERY");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($rows as $rs)
        {
            $voornaam = $rs["voornaam"]
    $achternaam = $rs["achternaam"]
    $omschrijving = $rs["omschrijving"]
            }
}

    // Just an example
    echo '<form action= "" method="post"> <input type="text" name="voornaam"      value="'. $voornaam .'" style="width:100px"><input name="submit" type ="submit"  value="Submit"><br/><br/>';
```

Value is also the input so you can have only one Submit button at the end cause all other data will be overwritten by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your switch you're sending `!empty($_POST)` so boolean (true or false) so unique cases would be: True or False...

It's better if you change your switch to:

```
if(isset($_POST[$row["voornaam"]]) && !empty($_POST[$row["voornaam"]])){
  // update SQL query 'firstname' here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo '<tr> <td class="tg">' .$row["id"]. '</td>' . "\n";
            echo '<td class="tg"> <form action= "" method="post"> <input type="text" name="voornaam"      value="'.$row["voornaam"].'" style="width:100px"> <input name="submit" type ="submit"  value="Aanpassen"><br/><br/>' . '</td>' . "\n";
            echo '<td class="tg"> <form action= "" method="post"> <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="'.$row["achternaam"].'" style="width:100px"> <input name="submit" type ="submit"  value="Aanpassen"><br/><br/>' . '</td>' . "\n"; 
            echo '<td class="tg"> <form action= "" method="post"> <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="'.$row["omschrijving"].'" style="width:500px"> <input name="submit" type ="submit"  value="Aanpassen"><br/><br/>' . '</td> </tr>' . "\n";
        }
}
else 
{
    echo "0 resultaten";
}


if( isset( $_POST[$row["voornaam"]] ) && !empty( $_POST[$row["voornaam"]] ) )
{
    // update SQL query 'firstname' here
}
    $conn->close();
?>
```